# trying to use "OR" and "AND" in the same JPA method signature

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
findByFloorIdAndCategoryOrAreaIdAndCategory
```

I need to query with `((flooId and category) or (areaId and category))` from the same table.
The above given name is not working. It's throwing the following error.

```
List<SpaceToDevice> spaceToDevices = spaceToDeviceRepository.findByFloorIdAndCategoryOrAreaIdAndCategory(id, category, id, category);
```

---

```
Error: with root causecom.azure.data.cosmos.CosmosClientException: 
    Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: 
    Message: {"Errors":["Invalid query. Specified duplicate parameter name '@category'."]}
```

Comment: Please add the error you get.

Comment: Code:                                                                                            
List<SpaceToDevice> spaceToDevices = spaceToDeviceRepository.findByFloorIdAndCategoryOrAreaIdAndCategory(id, category, id, category);                                                                                                                         Error:  with root causecom.azure.data.cosmos.CosmosClientException: Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"Errors":["Invalid query. Specified duplicate parameter name '@category'."]}

Answer (score 2):

While there might be a bug hiding you really shouldn't do this.

Query derivation intentionally doesn't offer any way to control the precedence between `AND` and `OR` operation. The idea behind query derivation is to create queries for simple method names where the SQL/JPQL is obvious from the method name alone. But names like `findByFloorIdAndCategoryOrAreaIdAndCategory` aren't names you would normally use (I hope) and therefore you shouldn't.

Instead choose a shorter, better name and add a `@Query` annotation or a named query.

As for a the potential bug: If you can provide a reproducer, please report it at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues